io detection from industrial contactor
Currently im working on detection of 230v main supply from an industrial contactor using mcu. There is a module available on global market for detecting 230v main using optical isolation for mcu's. I was thinking of using this module for detection of industrial contactor A1-A2 pins. With this way mcu will  detect if contactor signal applied from another industrail equipment or not. Yes, i know i can detect this with more safety ways like extra link module or another relay but what may happens if i use directly A1 - A2 pins ? As known , switching contactor coils will generate lots of emf and other stuffs but i curios about will this module fits for this application.
Contactor: SIEMENS 3RT2036-1AP01
Module:https://grobotronics.com/1-channel-optocoupler-isolation-module-voltage-detection-220v-ac.html?sl=en

If this was a voltage detection module from a well-known industrial automation company it would have a datasheet specifying the maximum voltage it can withstand. It would also cost a lot more.
This low-cost module doesn't specify a maximum voltage, and maybe the supplier doesn't know, because it hasn't been tested.
So using a no-name module is a risk; you need to think carefully about the consequences if this unit were to fail.

do you have recommended schema for this purpose or any other published known brand circuit ??

@qwertyqwq Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. But have you actually checked with the usual well-known companies making these kind of modules? Siemens, Wago, Phoenix and so on.
